# Cannot get input value in multi row table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have the following table definition :

```
  <table id = "domaintable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>  
            <th scope="col"> </th>
            <th scope="col">Domain Name</th>
        </thead>
        </tr>                         
    <tr id = "row1">
      <td id =><input type  = "checkbox" id = "domaincheck" data-domain-row="1" ></td>
      <td   align = "center" id = "domainID:1">1</td>
      <td align = "center" id = "domainname1"><input type = "text" name ="domainname" data-domainname-row= "1"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id = "row2" style="display:none;">
        <td id =><input type    = "checkbox" id = "domaincheck" data-domain-row="2" ></td>
        <td   align = "center" id   = "domainID:2">2</td>
        <td align = "center" id = "domainname2"><input type = "text" name ="domainname" data-domainname-row= "2"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr id = "row3" style="display:none;">
        <td id =><input type    = "checkbox" id = "domaincheck" data-domain-row="3" ></td>
        <td   align = "center" id   = "domainID:3">3</td>
        <td align = "center" id = "domainname3"><input type = "text" name ="domainname" data-domainname-row= "3"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr id = "row3" style="display:none;">
          <td id =><input type  = "checkbox" id = "domaincheck" data-domain-row="3" ></td>
          <td   align = "center" id = "domainID:3">3</td>
          <td align = "center" id = "domainname3"><input type = "text" name ="domainname" data-domainname-row= "3"></td>
        </tr>


        <tr id = "row4" style="display:none;">
            <td id =><input type    = "checkbox" id = "domaincheck" data-domain-row="4" ></td>
            <td   align = "center" id   = "domainID:4">4</td>
            <td align = "center" id = "domainname4"><input type = "text" name ="domainname" data-domainname-row= "4"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id = "row5" style="display:none;">
              <td id =><input type  = "checkbox" id = "domaincheck" data-domain-row="5" ></td>
              <td   align = "center" id = "domainID:5">5</td>
              <td align = "center" id = "domainname5"><input type = "text" name ="domainname" data-domainname-row= "5"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr id = "row6" style="display:none;">
                <td id =><input type    = "checkbox" id = "domaincheck" data-domain-row="6" ></td>
                <td   align = "center" id   = "domainID:6">6</td>
                <td align = "center" id = "domainname6"><input type = "text" name ="domainname" data-domainname-row= "6"></td>
              </tr>
    </table>
```

The above table has style set as "display:none" so that when not all rows are displayed at once and visibility is set only when user clicks on add row button which is working correctly with out any issues
I am using the following code to retrieve value entered in the table for each row :

```
var domaincount = $('#domaintable tr:visible').length-1; 
console.log(domaincount);
var domainnamehtml = $('[name = "domainname"]');         
console.log(domainnamehtml);
var domainnametable = [];
for (var i=0;i<domaincount;i++){
    console.log(domainnamehtml[i].value);
    if(domainnamehtml[i].value)
        domainnametable[i] = domainnamehtml[i].value;
    else
        domainnametable[i] = "blank";
 }
```

On executing the above code I find that the value entered in the 3rd or 4th row is set to blank even there is an input from the user on the same row. I even tried accessing the value on the page using the console debugger , but the value is set as blank.
Need help to understand what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: All ids must be unique you have duplicated `id = "domaincheck" ` so JS/ jQ will only acknowledge of the first one found. Also, even though everything else seems valid, the spacing is terrible you should keep attributes tight in HTML (ex. `<input id='checkDomain'>`)

Comment: Thanks @zer00ne - will ensure that the spacing is correct for the checkbox. Any comments on the input tag and the row?

Answer (score 0):

## [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) vs. [jQuery Object (or Collection)](https://api.jquery.com/category/miscellaneous/collection-manipulation/)

> *"On executing the above code I find that the value entered in the 3rd or 4th row is set to blank even there is an input from the user on the same row.  I even tried accessing the value on the page using the console debugger , but the value is set as blank."*

### Situation

- Let's say that you have 6 rows.
- The user hides the first 3 rows.
- You want the value of the inputs in the remaining 3 rows.

Using the OP (***O**riginal **P**ost*)<sup>✱</sup> code:

> ```
> var visibleIndex = $('#domaintable tr:visible').length-1;
> ```

That's an index of 2 for the loop that should cover 3 loops, that's logical.

> ```
> var names = $(`[name="domainName"]`);
> ```

Next is a jQuery Object of ***all tags*** with the `name` of `domainName`. That's ***6 inputs visible and hidden*** because a jQuery Collection (or Object) counts everything. So now going through the loop you'll get the values of the 3 hidden inputs and it stops after that. 
<sup><sup>✱</sup>The names have been modified for my sanity -- `domainthis` and `domainthat` begin to look simply like `domain`.</sup>

---

### Solutions

A quick fix is to change line 2:

> ```
> var names = $(`[name="domainName:visible"]`);
> ```

The following demo has a generic function for easy reuse, it uses [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method which is superior to a `for` loop, details are commented in demo. Also, the markup is a good example of proper HTML formatting. In addition, `id="checkDomain"` is invalid -- **all ids must be unique** -- so it has been changed to `class="checkDomain"`. Once you get used to using jQuery, using class becomes very simple and using id becomes a hindrance.

---

### Demo

```js
/* | Row | Pick one for ROW parameter */
// Results will be different
var vis = `#domains tbody tr:visible`;
var inv = `#domains tbody tr:hidden`;
var all = `#domains tbody tr`;

/* | jQuery Object | Pick one for jQObj parameter */
// They are different ways to access the same input
var name = '[name="domainName"]';
var data = '[data-domain]';
var type = ':text';

// Keep track of lines logged with a counter
var counter = 1;

/* Pass in a selector for rows and input */
function trLoop(ROW, jQObj) {
  
  // Log a line and increment counter
  console.log(`${counter++} ================`);
  
  // .each() runs a function on each row
  $(ROW).each(function() {
    
    /* Get the current row ---- $(this)
    ** Find the text input ---- .find(jQObj)
    ** Get that input's value - .val()
    */    
    var result = $(this).find(jQObj).val();  
    
    // If there's no value log: "Blank"...
    if (!result) {
      console.log('Blank');
    
    // ...otherwise log the value
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
  // Log a line after the last loop
  console.log(`==================`);
}

/* For demo purposes */
$('#add').on('click', function(e) {
  var count = Number($('[data-row]:last').data('row'))+1;
  $('#domains tbody').append(`<tr id="row${count}" class='show'>
          <td><input class="domainCheck" data-row="${count}" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>${count}</td>
          <td><input data-domain="${count}" name="domainName" type="text"  value=''></td>
          <td><button type='button'>Hide</button></td>
        </tr>`);
});

/* For demo purposes */
$('#domains tbody').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('tr').hide();
});

/* For demo purposes */
$(':radio:eq(0)').on('click', function(e) {trLoop(vis, name)});
$(':radio:eq(1)').on('click', function(e) {trLoop(inv, data)});
$(':radio:eq(2)').on('click', function(e) {trLoop(all, type)});
```

```css
/* All styles are for demo purposes*/
body {
  font: 400 16px Consolas
}

fieldset {
  width: 20%;
  float:left;
}

#domains {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  float:left;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10ch;
}

input, button {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:center;
  font: inherit;
}

button {
  width: 8ch;
}

.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 25%;
  min-height: 100%;
  transform:translateX(300%);
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content:'';
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <title></title>
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <style></style>
</head>

<body>
<!--fieldset for demo purposes-->
   <fieldset>
     <legend>Rows</legend>
     <label>Visible: </label> 
     <input type='radio' name='row'><br>
     <label>Invisible: </label>
     <input type='radio' name='row'><br>
     <label>All: </label>
     <input type='radio' name='row'>
   </fieldset>
   
  <table id='domains'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col">Domain Name</th>
          <th scope='col'>            
            <button id='add' type='button'>Add</button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="row1">
          <td><input class="domainCheck" data-row="1" type="checkbox" checked></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><input data-domain="1" name="domainName" type="text"  value='cdnjs.com'></td>
          <td><button type='button'>Hide</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2">
          <td><input class="domainCheck" data-row="2" type="checkbox" checked></td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td><input data-domain="2" name="domainName" type="text" value='stackoverflow.com'></td>
          <td><button type='button'>Hide</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row3">
          <td><input class="domainCheck" data-row="3" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td><input data-domain="3" name="domainName" type="text" value=''></td>
          <td><button type='button'>Hide</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row4">
          <td><input class="domainCheck" data-row="4" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td><input data-domain="4" name="domainName" type="text" value=''></td>
          <td><button type='button'>Hide</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row5">
          <td><input class="domainCheck" data-row="5" type="checkbox" checked></td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td><input data-domain="5" name="domainName" type="text" value='google.com'></td>
          <td><button type='button'>Hide</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```